# Changing the weights values in backprop, by how much?

Tags: regression, neural-networks, backpropagation

So im reading through [this](https://deeplearning4j.org/logistic-regression.html) link on Neural Nets and regression and on this page the part about back propagation which reads:

> To perform backpropagation and make the network learn, you simply compare ŷ to the ground-truth value of y and adjust the weights and biases of the network until error is minimized, much as you would with a classifier. Root-means-squared-error (RMSE) could be the loss function.

My question is how much do i adjust the weights and biases by? 
And in what order?

Now I know the second part of my question obvious answer is 'backwards' but what i mean is 

 *if im changing the weights from back to front. 
how can i know that if i change a weight near the input so it wont drastically mess up the Y? So I would have to go back to the weight near the output and change that so the weight near the input dosent make such a drastic change.*

Dose this make sense? if not I will clarify.

Answer (score 1):

This paragraph gives a very high-level overview of backpropagation. Backpropagation is a mathematical technique that relates the change of a weight to a change in the outcome.

A good discussion is [this](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html) chapter. As you can see, a whole chapter has been devoted to explaining it.

> At the heart of backpropagation is an expression for the partial
>   derivative $\partial C / \partial w $ of the cost function $C$ with respect to any weight $w$ (or bias $b$) in the network. The expression tells us how
>   quickly the cost changes when we change the weights and biases. And
>   while the expression is somewhat complex, it also has a beauty to it,
>   with each element having a natural, intuitive interpretation.

So the answer is that you adjust all weights and biases simultaneously by the amount calculated using backpropagation.